# Running an app converted with the Windows Desktop Bridge as admin always?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I have an app that I've converted using the [Desktop to UWP Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-manual-conversion), specifically the [Desktop App Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter) which does it all automatically. It converts and installs fine but when I try to run it I recieve an error that the executable requires elevation. I can resolve this with `Right Click -> Run as Administrator` but I'd like the repackage the app with this as a default so this extra step isn't required. It's noteworthy that I can run the app as a normal install without admin privileges, it is only the converted app that requires this.

Is there a way to include the required elevation request in the `AppxManifest.xml` file associated with converting the app? I was hoping there would be something as simple as

```
<Application Id="MyApp" Permissions="Administrator">
```

There are docs on the manifest [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-manual-conversion) but I can't find anything related to permissions or elevation levels.

This is the `AppxManifest.xml` generated by the converter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" xmlns:uap2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/2" xmlns:uap3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/3" xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" xmlns:desktop="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10">
  <Identity Name="MyApp" ProcessorArchitecture="x86" Publisher="CN=Me" Version="5.70.0.0" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>MyApp</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>Me</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\AppStoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="en-us" />
    <Resource uap:Scale="100" />
    <Resource uap:Scale="125" />
    <Resource uap:Scale="150" />
    <Resource uap:Scale="200" />
    <Resource uap:Scale="400" />
  </Resources>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14393.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
  </Capabilities>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="MyApp" Executable="Integrator.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="MyApp" Description="MyApp" BackgroundColor="transparent" Square150x150Logo="Assets\AppMedTile.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\AppList.png">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\AppWideTile.png" Square310x310Logo="Assets\AppLargeTile.png" Square71x71Logo="Assets\AppSmallTile.png">
          <uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
            <uap:ShowOn Tile="square150x150Logo" />
            <uap:ShowOn Tile="wide310x150Logo" />
            <uap:ShowOn Tile="square310x310Logo" />
          </uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
        </uap:DefaultTile>
      </uap:VisualElements>
      <Extensions>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap3:FileTypeAssociation Name="gfe">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>.gfe</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
          </uap3:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap3:FileTypeAssociation Name="gfs">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>.gfs</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
          </uap3:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.appExecutionAlias" Executable="Integrator.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
          <uap3:AppExecutionAlias>
            <desktop:ExecutionAlias Alias="Integrator5.exe" />
          </uap3:AppExecutionAlias>
        </uap3:Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** As of Windows 10 update 1809 (build 17763), you are now able to declare the 'allowElevation' capability to enable auto/self-elevation. Here is a tutorial on this capability: https://stefanwick.com/2018/10/01/app-elevation-samples-part-1/

**Previous answer (applies to pre-1809 builds of Windows 10):**
Auto-elevation for apps is not supported today. The user can choose to run your app as admin though.

This policy is called out in the preparation guide for the Desktop Bridge:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare
(bullet #2)

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform

Comment: Thanks for this. Like I mentioned the app runs without admin privileges when installed/run normally, it's only after converting with the bridge that it requires admin. Is there a reason the DAC would alter anything surrounding this?

Comment: Have you debugged through your code to see what operation exactly is triggering the request for elevation? You might have to make a code change in the app there.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT, can I at least have a button for user in my app to restart it as elevated?
I've been doing
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) { Verb = "runas" };
Process.Start(startInfo);

in desktop apps, but when packaged with Desktop Bridge, that call fails.

Comment: No, this is not supported. Only way is for the user to right-click and choose "Run as administrator". Or launch the app from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: do I still need allowelevation flag if I am already using <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" /> ? how adding this flag affect the applicaiton if it already requires administartor ?

Comment: Without the allowelevation capability in the app package manifest your application will not be able to require elevation and thus not be able to launch, once it's packaged as a "desktop bridge" app in an MSIX package.

Comment: i removed the allowelevation and can still run via "run as administrator" did you mean that once i remove allowelevation it will not trigger UAC ?

Comment: the app can't self-elevate or request elevation via UAC without this capability

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT ok so basically this flag triggers UAC when app is run as standard user.  I have notice another issue it may be a bug in Os not sure but when you have built-in Administrator active and also have User with Admin privileges account, and you run this app as **standard users**  UAC will **shows up twice** and if you use User with Admin credentials the app will not run, you need to enter built-in administrator credentials is this normal ?

Comment: @IronHide that sounds strange. I'd recommend you start a new question on this with all the repro details.

Comment: Actually I have also downloaded your project (part 1) straight from GitHub compiled it and run and under standard user account UAC in not triggered a just warning that app requires elevation. Then when I force it via "run as administrator" UAC shows twice and still fails. Can you confirm that this is still working on your end ? Or is something broken on msft side ?

Comment: My personal blog is not official, supported content. I no longer work in this space, so I am not authority any changes that might have happened since I published that blog years ago. Please open a new question, or use Microsoft support channels such as Microsoft Q&A or the MSIX Techcommunity.